# Why do not need to install usb driver when I connect to android device on mac?

Tags: android, macos, driver, device

I use osx10 later and have android phone. I installed android studio and connected phone on mac by usb cable. My sample app is well run with android phone.

But windows systems need to install use driver to connect android device.

Why do not need to install usb driver when I connect to android device on mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux and OSX comes with USB drivers so additional drivers are not required. USB drivers are required only in case of windows, details can be found on below official pages.
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Answer (score 1):

Linux and OSX come with a generic USB driver that allows devices to connect without additional drivers